# Is there a wiring design that would protect a person in bath from electrocution when a powered appliance is dropped?

Tags: safety, wiring

Hairdryer falling into bath is a Hollywood cliche already. Jokes aside, is there a wiring design that would protect a person in this case?

Overcurrent protection will trip too late, residual current will not help - current through phase and neutral can be equal. Shaver sockets are great, but they output limited power.

Is there a wiring design that would allow using high-power mains-powered appliances and still protect a person against electrocution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but ...

**1. But:** One can always dream up more and more bizarre ways of killing yourself and then ask how to make it safe. "I am handing underneath a speeding stage coach as it ...". This falls in that class. Most regulatory authorities prohibit the use of portable high power electrical equipment in bathrooms and also prohibit the installation of other than special low power and isolated electrical outlets, in order to head off things like hair dryers and speeding stage coaches at the pass.

Anyone who would use a hairdryer while in a bath should feel comfortable playing Russian roulette. Anyone allowing another person to use a hairdryer while standing above them while they are in a bath should be comfortable being a machete throwers target.

**2. Yes:** Despite the forgoing, it should be able to be made ""reasonably" [tm] safe.

An RCD **will** work.   You say that , *"residual current will not help - current through phase and neutral can be equal."* but this is extremely unlikely to be true - and it it as true there would be no danger. Current "enters" via one mains lead and "returns" via the other. If entering and returning current are balanced then, whether immersed in air or water, no current flow exists to cause problems for the user. Water is a moderately good insulator but when contaminants are added it can conduct quit well. If the bath has a path to earth - either due to an earthed  metal plug connection or an informal path, then if more than a few mA of current flows to ground an RCD (residual current device) would trip.

**Adding an earthed metal plate or body to a hairdryer will make an RCD work better**. Most hairdryers and similar are purposefully not equipped with an earth connection but, as the challenge is to make the appliance "bath safe", provision of a generous earth framework would provide an immediate earth path for current when dropped in water and trip an RCD very promptly.This "tripping plate" could be entirely within the hairdryer and insualted from user contact but designed to be sure to be in contact with water if the appliance was dropped in water.

**An isolating transformer will increase safety** BUT has a 'gotcha' mode. If the voltage is not ground referenced then there can be no current flow from mains through water and user to ground. **But** there can still notionally be flow from eg phase, through water back to neutral. The voltage drop across the water would also become voltage drop across the user. It is not obvious how much current would flow via this essentially high resistance path but quite likely not much. As under 10 mA can be fatal, there may be enough. In this case, use of an isolating transformer would prevent an RCD operating and would increase the chance of user shock. It would be easy enough to measure how pronounced this out and back again flow was likely to be.

Comment: When I said "current through phase and neutral" I meant the following scenario: that there would be a parallel path "phase->water->human->water->neutral" and it would have dangerously high current.

Comment: @sharptooth - covered above. IF there is even a modest ground path an RCD will trip. 110VAC gives 10 mA at 11 kohm. 230 VAC at 23 kohm. // If there is no ground path user MAY be safe - as above, easy and interesting experiment suggests itself.

Comment: How about having a metal sense wire in the dryer, one end of which is connected to neutral via 1M resistor, and the other end of which is connected via second 1M resistor to a sensing circuit, which injects a capacitively-coupled medium-frequency AC signal (a few KHz or so) and makes sure the sense wire looks like a 2M resistance to neutral?

Comment: @supercat: Various electronic solutions are certainly possible. If the house wiring was not modified they would then need to either short circuit the mains to blow a fuse or safely disconnect mains so the immersed appliance was safe (which would be a good solution). BUT an earthed metal shield inside the appliance and an RCD would achieve the same result at minimal effort and cost. Having an RCD on a bathroom circuit is an extremely good idea regardless.

Comment: While I agree with your answer in general, this is trivially false: "If entering and returning current are balanced then, whether immersed in air or water, no current flow exists to cause problems for the user." A current flow from left hand, through the body, out the right hand is problematic, even without any ground leakage.

Comment: @Nick - No rudeness intended - but it would be false only if the context of the paragraph and context of the whole answer is ignored. In my final section ("An Isolating transformer ..." ) I specifically address the point you are making and note that an isolating transformer will make this possible. In the paragraph that you refer to I note the role and need for an earthed environment to prevent this "super balanced arrangement". An earthed plug surround and an RCD is highly liable to provide the protection needed in this environment. But still a potentially shocking experience for the user.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: If one were to plug two hair dryers into the same RCD/GFCI-protected outlet and immerse both in an insulated bathtub, it might be possible for current to flow out of one, through a person, and into the other, without tripping the protector.  It seems relatively unlikely, however, that significant current could leave a not-directly-exposed part of an appliance, go through the user, and return to the same appliance through some other not-directly-exposed part.

Comment: @supercat Really? Would you be prepared to test that? My point, though, was that whether or not the current through the phase and return wires is equal is irrelevant to the harm or lack thereof that it does - it's other factors that matter.

Comment: @All - I'd be prepared to test this - but not with my body. This is of sufficient interest that it would be intriguing to do some experiments. Not much effort involved to do this, **but** it may have to wait until another lifetime :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's called a GFCI - Ground Fault Current Interrupter.

Shocks are mostly caused by a combination of live-neutral and live-earth. Now although live-neutral can't be protected against, as it is how most devices draw their current, live-earth can.

An imbalance of more than 20mA (or thereabouts) between live and neutral currents indicates the current is going somewhere else, probably through the earth conductor.

This triggers the GFCI / EFCB / RCD breaker protecting you. This is one of the reasons plumbing must *always* be earthed.

Don't try this at home though!

Comment: I don't get it - does it rely on earthing being so conductive that there's always a live-earth leak? What if the bath is plastic and therefore insulating and the dryer has no protective earth wire?

Comment: @sharptooth I think there must be something metal in the bath for example the plug hole and drain is probably metal and earthed.

Comment: In my apartment the bath is steel and painted and all drain pipes are plastic.

Comment: You asked for a wiring design that would work. The appliance can be part of that. Th bath design can be part of that. In many administrations earthing of the bath and or drain metal is required. Informal earthing of bath will usually exist from dampness. You could design a death trap if you tried hard enough but reality errs on the side of the RCD here.

Comment: You could easily measure this. Make a longish 1 kW heater element. Immerse in water in insulated container and see how much potential exists across water at locations away from the element. YMMV.

Comment: @Thomas O You answered this question from a consumer electronics or home-improvement perspective. A good answer for us would explain how you would actually make such a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The closes thing is the shaver socket.

All it consists of is a 1:1 transformer.  The reason they can't give much power is the transformer is small and can't transfer much power.

A larger 1:1 transformer should allow a larger power transfer.

These 1:1 transformers are called "Isolation Transformers".

It will still never be 100% "safe" though, and the situation should be avoided whenever possible.  Shaver sockets are designed for dropping a shaver in a sink - not a hair drier in the bath where you are fully immersed.

Comment: Note these transformers include a built-in thermal cut-off which triggers at around 20W.